# Can a form execution occur twice?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, post, browser

I've obviously missed something somewhere.

In some way a customer has managed to do a booking twice within a 11 seconds delay (checked time). My first though was that the user might have done the booking, then backed in the browser and done the booking again. However this is not possible since I had at least 2 validations which I know would prevent this behavior.

The only conclusion left for me is if the customer tried to submit a booking, our webservice somehow froze in maybe 11 seconds, the customer aborted the request and submited again, therefor allowing these 2 bookings to happend at the same moment.

Apart from that, I got no idea what could cause it. Delay in MySQL insert perhaps?

So basicly what I wonder mostly is;
**What can cause a form to get submited and executed twice, with the second one bypassing all required validation?**

### Current workflow of my form

A user submits data in input fields, and then submits them. My system validates all of these inputs and check for both a unique code to make sure that it's not used twice through a MySQL call. It also makes sure the number of seats available is equal or greator than then amount of seats booked.

In this mentioned case, both the same code was used and the seats over extended allowed limit.

Basicly the booking won't be inserted into MySQL unless the POST is validated.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you attach your validation method(s), otherwise this is like marble reading

Comment: The validation process can't be understood easily. I will put it up if not someone knows an other cause. The validation does what it's supposed to do once I try it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My system validates all of these inputs and check for both a unique
>   code to make sure that it's not used twice through a MySQL call.

Sounds like you have a concurrency issue. Do you lock the table while doing the checks/insert?

In theory, if two executions occur at the same time, they will both have a unique ID and be within the seat limit, so both insertions will be allowed to proceed (and thus succeed).

Here is a diagrammatic way of what I am thinking:

```
POST 1                  POST 2
Unique ID: 1234         Unique ID: 1234
Check if ID is present  Check if ID is present
ID is not present       ID is not present
Check if seats left     Check if seats left
Make insert             Make insert
```

The second make `POST 2` should not be allowed to begin it's unique ID check until the table is unlocked, i.e. `POST 1` has finished it's insert.

Comment: I've never though about this behavior. I guess this kind of "errors" might occur more often if your web service is slow? How would I enforce this behavior upon MySQL?

Comment: I can't speak about MySQL's scheduler specifically, but they're generally non-deterministic. We can't guarantee whether it'd execute the queries one after the other, or at the same time, if it receives them together. Your issue can easily by fixed by issuing a [LOCK TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) at the start, and `UNLOCK TABLES` at the end of your script.

Comment: It will be a bit hard to know, but this must be the cause of the problem. I'll mark it Correct and keep an open eye to if the problem persists after the LOCK TABLE solution.

Answer (score 0):

The user could have refreshed the page where the form is processed, thus sending the POST information twice? Where is your validation located, if it just stops the form from being displayed, instead of being processed, then this could be a possibility?

Comment: this is no answer but a comment.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if the user refreshes the page where the POST information is processed and there are no checks on this page to stop this from happening. Clearer?

True, it was not an answer, but it was a suggestion.

Comment: @mightyuhu at 49 rep can he add comments?

Comment: No, I can't add comments (to anything but my own posts).